# Calculate distance to shore or coastline for a vessel

Tags: python, geometry, gis

For a dataset of 200M GPS (lon, lat) coordinates of vessels I want to calculate an approximate distance to the nearest land or coastline, as a function called distance_to_shore, that will return the distance and country of that shore.

I'm using a shape file of country boundaries and coastlines from: http://www.naturalearthdata.com/

Some considerations are that the Oceanic pole of inaccessibility is 2688 km. So this would be the maximum possible distance from shore, this could be used to create some kind of bounding box. I want to calculate accounting for the Earth's curvature (not Euclidean), e.g. Haversine, or Vincenty method.

For this I started looking at scipy.spatial.cKDTree, but this does not allow for Haversine distance metric. On the other hand the sklearn.neighbors.BallTree, does allows for Haversine distance metric but I can't get it to work. Here is the code I have so far. N.B. the function should ideally be vectorized.

**###############################**
**SOLUTION**
**###############################**

Thanks for all the input this is how I solved it in Python, including functions to download relevant shape files, needs some cleaning

```
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

import shapely as sp
import cartopy.io.shapereader as shpreader
import ssl
import urllib.request
import zipfile

from shutil import rmtree
from dbfread import DBF
from scipy import spatial
from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors, BallTree
from pyproj import Proj, transform

from math import *

coastline = np.load(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),
                    '../data/shape_files/coast_coords_10m.npy'))

ports = np.load(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),
                '../data/shape_files/ports_coords.npy'))

def extract_geom_meta(country):
    '''
    extract from each geometry the name of the country
    and the geom_point data. The output will be a list
    of tuples and the country name as the last element.
    '''
    geoms = country.geometry
    coords = np.empty(shape=[0, 2])
    for geom in geoms:
        coords = np.append(coords, geom.exterior.coords, axis = 0)

    country_name = country.attributes["ADMIN"]
    return [coords, country_name]

def save_coastline_shape_file():
    '''
    store shp files locally, this functions will download
    shapefiles for the whole planet.
    '''
    ne_earth = shpreader.natural_earth(resolution = '10m',
                                       category = 'cultural',
                                       name='admin_0_countries')
    reader = shpreader.Reader(ne_earth)
    countries = reader.records()
    # extract and create separate objects
    world_geoms = [extract_geom_meta(country) for country in countries]
    coords_countries = np.vstack([[np.array(x[:-1]), x[-1]]
                                    for x in world_geoms])
    coastline = np.save(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),
                        '../data/shape_files/coast_coords_10m.npy')
                        , coords_countries)
    print('Saving coordinates (...)')

def distance_to_shore(lon, lat):
    '''
    This function will create a numpy array of distances
    to shore. It will contain and ID for AIS points and
    the distance to the nearest coastline point.
    '''
    coastline_coords = np.vstack([np.flip(x[0][0], axis=1) for x in coastline])
    countries = np.hstack([np.repeat(str(x[1]), len(x[0][0])) for x in coastline])
    tree = BallTree(np.radians(coastline_coords), metric='haversine')
    coords = pd.concat([np.radians(lat), np.radians(lon)], axis=1)
    dist, ind = tree.query(coords, k=1)
    df_distance_to_shore = pd.Series(dist.flatten()*6371, name='distance_to_shore')
    df_countries = pd.Series(countries[ind].flatten(), name='shore_country')
    return pd.concat([df_distance_to_shore, df_countries], axis=1)
```

Comment: As cool as this question seems, I cant really even comprehend why it would need a solution. By the time your done running your computations, all 200M vessels will have reached their destination....

Comment: @william-grimes Any feedback on the python solution I provided?  It should work "out of the box".  A bummer is that the vptree implementation is rather inefficient; however it's still streaks better than an exhaustive search.  A further possible optimization would be to say you only need to find the closest coast if it's withing 100km (say).

Comment: Your solution uses the great circle distance.  I tried using the user-defined metric 'pyfunc' specifying the geodesic distance with BallTree.  This gets the correct answer but is considerably slower than vptree; for a tree with 30000 points, it takes 144.5 distance calculations per query vs 16.7 for vptree.

Comment: @cffk the vptree implementation can be converted into Cython from Python making it even faster !

Comment: @gansub Probably...  However, presumably most of the time is spent doing the distance calculations, so this would need to be converted too.

Comment: @cffk you mean the pyproj code as well ?

Comment: @gansub Actually I was talking about the native python implementation in the GeographicLib package.  pyproj includes the C implementation so that's already fast.

Comment: @cffk does pyproj include GeographicsLib now ? aren't they merged ?

Comment: @gansub pyproj includes proj.4 which includes the C implementation of only the geodesic routines in GeographicLib.

Answer (score 9):

The efficient way of solving this problem is to store all your coast
points into a [vantage point tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vantage-point_tree) using the geodesic distance as
your metric (it's important that the metric satisfy the
[triangle inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality)).  Then for each vessel you can query the VP
tree to find the closed point.

If there are *M* coast points and *N* vessels.  Then the time to
construct the VP tree requires *M* log *M* distance calculations.  Each
query requires log *M* distance calculations.  A distance calculation
for the ellipsoid takes about 2.5 μs.  So the total time is
(*M* + *N*) log *M* × 2.5 μs.

Here is code using my library [GeographicLib](https://geographiclib.sourceforge.io) (version 1.47 or later)
to carry out this calculation.  This is just a stripped-down version of
the example given for the [NearestNeighbor class](https://geographiclib.sourceforge.io/1.49/classGeographicLib_1_1NearestNeighbor.html).

```cpp
// Example of using the GeographicLib::NearestNeighbor class.  Read lon/lat
// points for coast from coast.txt and lon/lat for vessels from vessels.txt.
// For each vessel, print to standard output: the index for the closest point
// on coast and the distance to it.

// This requires GeographicLib version 1.47 or later.

// Compile/link with, e.g.,
// g++ -I/usr/local/include -lGeographic -L/usr/local/bin -Wl,-rpath=/usr/local/lib -o coast coast.cpp

// Run time for 30000 coast points and 46217 vessels is 3 secs.

#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>

#include <GeographicLib/NearestNeighbor.hpp>
#include <GeographicLib/Geodesic.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace GeographicLib;

// A structure to hold a geographic coordinate.
struct pos {
    double _lat, _lon;
    pos(double lat = 0, double lon = 0) : _lat(lat), _lon(lon) {}
};

// A class to compute the distance between 2 positions.
class DistanceCalculator {
private:
    Geodesic _geod;
public:
    explicit DistanceCalculator(const Geodesic& geod) : _geod(geod) {}
    double operator() (const pos& a, const pos& b) const {
        double d;
        _geod.Inverse(a._lat, a._lon, b._lat, b._lon, d);
        if ( !(d >= 0) )
            // Catch illegal positions which result in d = NaN
            throw GeographicErr("distance doesn't satisfy d >= 0");
        return d;
    }
};

int main() {
    try {
        // Read in coast
        vector<pos> coast;
        double lat, lon;
        {
            ifstream is("coast.txt");
            if (!is.good())
                throw GeographicErr("coast.txt not readable");
            while (is >> lon >> lat)
                coast.push_back(pos(lat, lon));
            if (coast.size() == 0)
                throw GeographicErr("need at least one location");
        }

        // Define a distance function object
        DistanceCalculator distance(Geodesic::WGS84());

        // Create NearestNeighbor object
        NearestNeighbor<double, pos, DistanceCalculator>
            coastset(coast, distance);

        ifstream is("vessels.txt");
        double d;
        int count = 0;
        vector<int> k;
        while (is >> lon >> lat) {
            ++count;
            d = coastset.Search(coast, distance, pos(lat, lon), k);
            if (k.size() != 1)
                    throw GeographicErr("unexpected number of results");
            cout << k[0] << " " << d << "\n";
        }
    }
    catch (const exception& e) {
        cerr << "Caught exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
        return 1;
    }
}
```

This example is in C++.  To use python, you'll need to find a python
implementation of VP trees and then you can use the
[python version of GeographicLib](https://geographiclib.sourceforge.io/html/python) for the distance calculations.

P.S.  GeographicLib uses an accurate algorithm for the geodesic distance
that satisfies the triangle inequality.  The Vincenty method fails to
converge for nearly antipodal points and so does *not* satisfy the triangle
inequality.

**ADDENDUM**: here's the python implementation:
Install vptree and geographiclib

```
pip install vptree geographiclib
```

coast points (lon,lat) are in coast.txt; vessel positions (lon,lat) are
in vessels.txt.  Run

```
import numpy
import vptree
from geographiclib.geodesic import Geodesic

def geoddist(p1, p2):
  # p1 = [lon1, lat1] in degrees
  # p2 = [lon2, lat2] in degrees
  return Geodesic.WGS84.Inverse(p1[1], p1[0], p2[1], p2[0])['s12']

coast = vptree.VPTree(numpy.loadtxt('coast.txt'), geoddist)
print('vessel closest-coast dist')
for v in numpy.loadtxt('vessels.txt'):
  c = coast.get_nearest_neighbor(v)
  print(list(v), list(c[1]), c[0])
```

<s>For 30000 coast points and 46217 vessels, this takes 18 min 3 secs.
This is longer than I expected.  The time to construct the tree is
1 min 16 secs.  So the total time *should* be about 3 min.</s>

For 30000 coast points and 46217 vessels, this takes 4 min (using
version 1.1.1 of vptree).
For comparison, the time using the [GeographicLib](https://geographiclib.sourceforge.io) C++ library is 3
secs.

<s>**LATER**: I looked into why the python vptree is slow.  The number of
distance calculations to set up the tree is the same for GeographicLib's
C++ implementation and python vptree package: 387248 which is about *M*
log *M*, for *M* = 30000.  (Here logs are base 2 and I set the bucket
size to 1 for both implementations to ease comparisons.)  The mean
number of distance calculations for each vessel lookup for the C++
implementation is 14.7 which is close to the expected value, log *M* =
14.9.  However the equivalent statistic for the python implementation is
108.9, a factor for 7.4 larger.</s>

Various factors influence the efficiency of the VP tree: the choice of
vantage points, how the search is ordered, etc.  A discussion of these
considerations for the GeographicLib implementation is given [here](https://geographiclib.sourceforge.io/1.49/nearest.html).
I will ping the author of the python package about this.

**STILL LATER**:  I've submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/RickardSjogren/vptree/pull/2) which cures the major
problems with the efficiency of the python package vptree.  The CPU time for
my test is now about 4 min.  The number of distance calculations per query is
16.7 (close to the figure for GeographicLib::NearestNeighbor, 14.7).

Comment: what is coast.txt in this example?

Comment: coast.txt is a list of points in the format "longitude latitude", one point per line, and in degrees.  This gives a list of points on the coast.  vessel.txt is similar, giving the positions of the vessels.

Comment: Where can I get `coast.txt` to make your code work on Python in Linux? Or better yet, how can I edit your code to accept any of the coast files from https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/50m-physical-vectors/50m-coastline/ ?

Comment: Run shpdump on the shapefile (extension .shp) you get after unzipping the dataset.  Then you can easily extract the longitude latitude pairs.

Comment: Extracting (lat,lon) from a .shp file is more complicated than that; i recommend the `shapefile` package. Also, you have an error: `vptree.VPTree` needs 2 arguments, not 3, so delete `8`. Question: is there a way to make `Geodesic.WGS84.Inverse` accept DataFrame arguments, i.e. compute distances between several pairs of points simultaneously? Simlarly, is there a way to vectorize the query `coast.get_nearest_neighbor(v)`, i.e. make it work for an array `v` of several points?

Answer (score 0):

The key here is that you need to use the "great circle" (orthodromic) distance calculations, which are designed to find the **distance between two points on the surface of a sphere**.  Although the earth is not a perfect sphere, such calculations will get you very close (to within 0.5%), and non-spherical adjustments can be applied if this isn't close enough.

There are many documentations of this formula on the internet.  You will want to look for closed form solutions that involve X-Y-Z instead of polar coordinates, or convert your GPS coordinates into polar, one of the two.

Answer (score 0):

You need a Great Circle distance calculation formula. These are sometimes called *Spherical Cosine Law*, *Haversine,* or *Vincenty*, formulas.

You can then compute the distance from each vessel to the nearest point in your coastline corpus. It's often helpful to use a bounding box computation to rule out irrelevant points before running the whole Great Circle formula on them.

When you construct your coastline corpus, you may need to use interpolation to add extra coastline points if your raw coastline data has long segments in it. That's because you're computing distance to the nearest *point* not the nearest *segment*. Look up Great Circle interpolation.

If your vessels are near either pole (well, near the North pole, seeing as how the South pole is on land) things are going to get funky with the standard Great Circle formulas and bounding rectangles. You probably should use the Vincenty formulation in that case.

Here's a writeup on using a DBMS with indexing for this kind of purpose. https://www.plumislandmedia.net/mysql/haversine-mysql-nearest-loc/

If you need NOAA-chart level accuracy, you probably need to learn about Universal Transverse Mercator projections. That's beyond the scope of a Stack Overflow answer.